# Laravel localization methods

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-blade

I was wondering if there are some pros/cons in localization by using one approach over the other. I have a `@yield` in my main layout template and when extended in another view one solution is to have this:

```
@section('page_title')
    @lang('common.landing_page.head_title')
@endsection
```

I was looking if there is a more elegant solution since I have few of these sections and I would like to reduce 3 lines to one if possible, so I did this:

```
@section('page_title', trans('common.landing_page.head_title'))
```

So my question is whether there are any significant differences in form of performance, unnecessary coupling or something when using second approach?

Comment: Why not replace `@section('page_title')` with just `trans` invocation?

Comment: How would it function on another page which extends same layout? I couldn't have different titles then

Comment: Try and test, isn't it?

Comment: I don't get what you're aiming at. If I put `trans()` in my main layout, it will fetch only one string (in this case `head_title` for landing page). If I go to inbox page, I won't see `inbox` as a title, but the same string as for landing page. What is there to test?

Comment: What laravel version is this?

Comment: 4.2. ---Typing because it doesn't let me submit number only---